# Xpath Error: Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList

Tags: xpath

In one of the API solution, incoming request is in XML format, and i need to fetch first child node tag name to make decision to run the logic. I am using xpath to get the tag name, when in am running xpath i am getting error **"Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList"**

I have tried with local-name and name, but both are giving same error.
my xml is as below

```
<p:Check xmlns:p="http://amarwayx.com.cu/WCSXMLSchema/creptonium">
            <AttributeChnageLocal>
                <TaskID>17723</TaskID>
                <BatchID>12345</BatchID>
                <Expiry>2022-12-06</Expiry> 
                <TimeStamp>2019-07-20T22:45:48</TimeStamp> 
            </AttributeChnageLocal>
        </p:Check>
```

and Xpath i used are

```
    local-name(/p:Check/*)
    name(/p:Check/*)
    local-name(/p:Check/*[1])
    name(/p:Check/*[1])
```

how ever is some online xpath evaluator has evaluated correct name(AttributeChnageLocal), i am not getting where the xpath syntax is wrong. 
below is my tool snapshot.
[image]

same kind of expression works fine
[image]

Comment: Are you storing the xpath return value to a `node`? It should be stored in a `String` as above xpaths' will return string value. Can you please the line of code where you are getting the error.

Comment: I am storing result as string, i have a product which handles evrything, we just need to execute correct xpath, added snapshot in question

Comment: Check the logic associated to the first radio button, if it's trying to get the text from the node.

Answer (score 1):

You have ticked a box labelled "store the string value of the selected node as text", which suggests that the XPath evaluation tool you are using expects your XPath expression to select a node; but it doesn't, it selects a string.

I don't know what this tool you are using is, but unfortunately all its options seem to assume that you are selecting nodes.

Comment: Thaks for your reply, In same tool same kind of xpath expression works fine, I have added snapshot in question, I am not getting point why same expression gives two different result

Comment: I don't know the tool in question so I can't offer any more help.